# Why doesn't spring framework bind my YAML list to an entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to bind a list of objects to my entity class using @ConfigurationProperties annotation. Spring Boot framework seems to ignore that annotation, and it literally does nothing.

Here is my application.yml properties file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search-engine
    username: landsreyk
    password: 12345678
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
sites:
  - url: http://someurl1.com
    name: somename1
  - url: https://someurl2.com
    name: somename2
  - url: https://someurl3.com
    name: somename3
```

And here is my entity class:

```
package main.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "_site")
public class Site {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "status_time")
    private Timestamp statusTime;

    @Column(name = "last_error")
    private String lastError;

    private String url;

    private String name;

    public enum Status {
        INDEXING, INDEXED, FAILED
    }
}
```

Binding is pretty straight forward:

```
package main.utilities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import main.model.Site;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.List;

@ConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationProperties {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Site> sites;

}
```

Somewhere in application I'm testing that binding, let's say I created end point in my API to test that binding, i.e. my controller calls a method which just prints all objects in a list:

```
package main.application.indexer;

import main.utilities.ApplicationProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class IndexBuilder {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties properties;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(properties.getSites());
    }

}
```

**Expected:**

After launch, ApplicationProperties instance is not null. Calling properties.getSites() returns a list of Site objects. Each Site object has url and name fields initialized from yaml source.

**Actual:**

After launch ApplicationProperties instance is null.

I was shocked to realize that Spring wasn't able to accomplish such a simple binding.
Knowing that just parsing a yaml file is not such a hard task to accomplish, I thought that Spring Framework should have this feature build-in.
How do I bind my list?

By the way, here is my project structure.

[image]

## **UPDATE:**

I edited IndexBuilder class. Added @Configuration and @Bean annotations.
Now it looks like this:

```
package main.application.indexer;

import main.utilities.ApplicationProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class IndexBuilder {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(properties.getSites());
    }

}
```

That fixed the problem with initialization, but Spring Framework just call run() immideately after launch. That isn't an expected behavior.

## **UPDATE 2:**

Answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323935/dpr) user is completely authentic.
He is right.

Comment: is `IndexBuilder` a `@Bean` (or @component/service/repository)??

Comment: Non of the above. IndexBuilder is a test class.

Comment: Auto wiring will only work on classes managed by spring. That is Bean, Component, …

Comment: But, what if I have utility class. Which annotation applies to that?

Comment: By the way, you really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `@Configuration` you should use `@Component` on your `IndexBuilder` class.

`@Configuration` should only be used for configuration classes that define the application‘s beans. Here it is actually expected that the methods annotated with `@Bean` are executed immediately on application start. This is the phase where spring creates all needed beans. However I’m wondering spring accepts a `void` method with the `@Bean` annotation.

What’s your expected time when the run method should be executed? With a normal bean/component/service you could for example use the `@PostConstruct` annotation on methods. These will however be executed in the very same phase as the `@Bean` methods or at least not much later.

Comment: Expected execution time - after controller calls it. It's obvious that I don't want to execute it before that.

Comment: Ok, I don’t think there is anything obvious here. Make `run` a normal public method (no annotations) on `IndexBuilder`, inject your `IndexBuilder` into your controller using autowiring and call the method whenever you like. You should really go through some spring tutorials to get an idea of how spring is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, Spring isn't that smart as I thought.

To access @ConfigurationProperties class, that is: accessing a bean from a non-managed-by-spring class, - I had to go through this article:

Autowiring Spring Beans Into Classes Not Managed by Spring
https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring

It solved the problem.

Comment: Spring cannot do magic, that's one of the most important things to know, when working with Spring (even if it sometimes seems like magic, it's not).